# Does WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw live beyond the current activity?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using the method `WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()` on one of my web views since I want to save its content to a file.

The problem is that I have other web views that I want them to use the optimisations that the new web view provides.

Does anyone know if this configuration is app-wide or if there is a way to disable slow whole document draw?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

If you take a look at the source code you can see that `WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()` implicitly calls the following:

```
getFactory().getStatics().enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
```

`getFactory()` returns the `WebViewFactoryProvider` instance which is providing all the `WebView`s for the current process.

You cannot disable it for a particular `WebView`.